# what effects MySQL search speed among largertexts, smalltexts, number, string? and how does it effect?

Tags: mysql, search

I'm pretty confused about what makes searches fast and what slow.
Does it search faster a 50 chars long text than 100, among 1 million rows?....
or how does it effects in case of a string or for an integer search?

Answer (score 1):

Searching is fastest on integer and is slowest on long text. As simple as that.
If your data contains long text columns, you can also create index with limited characters on that column.

Similarly, search will be faster for shorter text than longer one.

If you extensively use text columns and have to search in between huge text fields, better go for FULL TEXT SEARCH (available in InnoDB too from MySQL 5.6 onwards).

If you have more reads than writes and don't require referential integrity and transactions, you may use MyISAM (along with full text search) which will be fast enough.

Comment: And what would effect in pure integer search and mixed string search, eg: 123456789 and 753m2s93i

Comment: In that case, pure integer search should be faster. Remember, though it is mixed string in 2nd case, it is still a varchar/char.